# Is there another way to use onTextChanged for TextBox and avoid page refreshing every time?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a JavaScript which is doing some calculations from text fields and every time I pass on other text field JavaScript is called on action in TextBox 'onTextChanged' which require AutoPostBack = True but that every time doing refreshing of my page and because that I need every time to click twice on TextBox.

I have already tried to put this line of code on PageLoad but it still required 'AutoPostBack = True' and it also doing refreshing of page :

```
 CType(Me.FV.FindControl("txtLP_1"), TextBox).Attributes.Add("onblur", "javascript:startCalc();")
```

This is how looks like code on PageLoad:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then

    End If

    CType(Me.FV.FindControl("txtLP_1"), TextBox).Attributes.Add("onblur", "javascript:startCalc();")

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you sure you require AutoPostBack? This is to capture a server side event. It sounds like you are only capturing a client side event at that time.

Comment: If I remove AutoPostBack from the TextBox then it doesn't call my JavaScript. You are right for a client side event.

Comment: This would suggest an issue with binding the client side event. Can you post your entire page load?

Comment: Ok, page load looks fine. You definitely should not require the AutoPostBack. If you turn it off, are you getting any JS errors in your browser console? Maybe change the startCalc method to simply have an alert line to see if that kicks in: alert('Hello World');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of setting `AutoPostBack="True"` and invoking a post back everytime a value changes in your `TextBox` control why don't you just handle the text changed event through jQuery(completely client side)?

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#' + '<%: TextBox1.ClientID %>').on('input', function (e) {
                var value = $(this).val();
                alert(value);
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: I have tried this:  <script type="text/javascript">
                       $(function () {     var a = $('#<%=FV.FindControl("txtLikPotra_1").ClientID%>').val();
                                alert(a);    });
                    </script> and I am getting this error : 0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: '$' is undefined

Comment: I just had to save jquery.min.js in my project so now works.

Comment: Denis, this jquery.min.js works fine with google chrom. How can I adjust it to work with Internet explorer?

Comment: Use F12 in IE to debug your javascript and see why it's not working.Try using another .js version.Google the problem and do some trial and error until you figure it out

Comment: I have already tried with Debugging. There is no error, probably I need to download some other library.

Comment: I am using Internet Explorer 11. The first syntax of accessing my text box from FormView was: $('#' + '<%:FV.FindControl("txtLikPotra_1").ClientID%>').on('input', function () { Now I changed it to this: $(document).on("keydown‌​", "input[type=text]", function (){ and works only trough the IE debugger.

Comment: I just removed console.log from code and everything ok now.